# How do I fix my bootstrap carousel from stacking images

Tags: bootstrap-4, carousel

My images just stack on top of one another with the indicators on the bottom image. This is also within a container/row if that matters. Thanks!

```html
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
 <ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
 </ol>
 <div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="carousel-item active">
   <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/portfolio/cobblecreek1.jpg" alt="First slide">
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
   <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/portfolio/cobblecreek2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
   <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/portfolio/cobblecreek1.jpg" alt="Third slide">
  </div>
 </div>
 <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
 </a>
 <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
 </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you included all the resources correctly?

//CSS//

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

//JS//

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Your can either include it directly using CDN or download and include it locally.

For more refer to https://codepen.io/Hassam92/pen/bZyMNr

Comment: Everything seems to be correct, even the codepen stuff stacks in my code...

Comment: Codepen is working fine on my browser. It might be a caching issue. Which browser you're using?